# Snakemake problem: Merge all files together with space delimiter instead of iterating through it

Tags: snakemake

I was trying to run a command which ideally looks like this,

`minimap2 -a -x map-ont -t 20 /staging/reference.fasta fastq/sample01.fastq | samtools view -bS -F 4 - | samtools sort -o fastq_minon/sample01.bam`

Similarly, I have multiple samples (referring to **fastq/sample01.fastq**) in the folder.

The snakemake file I wrote to automate this behaviour is, however, parsing all files at once in the command like,

`minimap2 -a -x map-ont -t 1 /staging/reference.fasta fastq/sample02.fastq fastq/sample03.fastq fastq/sample01.fastq | samtools view -bS -F 4 - | samtools sort -o fastq_minon/sample02.bam fastq_minon/sample03.bam fastq_minon/sample01.bam`

I have pasted the code and logs below. Please help me try to figure out this mistake.

**Code**

```
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("fastq/{smp}.fastq")
rule minimap:
    input:
        expand("fastq/{smp}.fastq", smp=SAMPLES)
    output:
        expand("fastq_minon/{smp}.bam", smp=SAMPLES)
    params:
        ref = FASTA
    threads: 40
    shell:
        """
        minimap2 -a -x map-ont -t {threads} {params.ref} {input} | samtools view -bS -F 4 - | samtools sort -o {output}
        """
```

**log**

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       minimap
        1

[Tue May  5 03:28:50 2020]
rule minimap:
    input: fastq/sample02.fastq, fastq/sample03.fastq, fastq/sample01.fastq
    output: fastq_minon/sample02.bam, fastq_minon/sample03.bam, fastq_minon/sample01.bam
    jobid: 0


        minimap2 -a -x map-ont -t 1 /staging/reference.fasta fastq/sample02.fastq fastq/sample03.fastq fastq/sample01.fastq | samtools view -bS -F 4 - | samtools sort -o fastq_minon/sample02.bam fastq_minon/sample03.bam fastq_minon/sample01.bam

Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       minimap
        1
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expand` function is used to create a list. Thus, in your rule `minimap`, you're telling snakemake that you want all fastq files as input and that the rule will produce as many bam files. What you want is a rule that will be triggered for every sample using a wildcard:

```
SAMPLES, = glob_wildcards("fastq/{smp}.fastq")

rule all:
    input: expand("fastq_minon/{smp}.bam", smp=SAMPLES)

rule minimap:
    input:
        "fastq/{smp}.fastq"
    output:
        "fastq_minon/{smp}.bam"
    params:
        ref = FASTA
    threads: 40
    shell:
        """
        minimap2 -a -x map-ont -t {threads} {params.ref} {input} | samtools view -bS -F 4 - | samtools sort -o {output}
        """
```

By defining all the files wanted in rule `all`, the rule `minimap` will be triggered as many times as necessary to create ONE bam file from ONE fastq file.

Have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526646) to understand the use of wildcards and expand.

Comment: I have a followup question about the same code. Where I have to merge all result files the code later on using **cat**. I tried,

```rule Merge:
    input:
        expand("fasta/{smp}.fasta", smp=SAMPLES)
    output: 
        "fasta/merged.fasta"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output.merge}
        """
```
But doesn't seem to be working

Comment: **@Eric** I have figure it out after some trial and error. Now it is way too clear. I didn't know that Snakemake looks for all the execution from the first rule (`rule all`). I just had to mention the final output in `rule all`. And it will execute the pipeline step by step until it reaches the output mentioned in `rule all`. I hope I am right. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you
Vivek

Comment: @Ted You're perfectly right. Snakemake is a top to bottom workflow manager. It looks at the final files you want and goes down the rules to produce them.